# how compile this program in lubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nasm

I'm trying to compile the following code. the problem is that it doesnt compile.
i use lubuntu , and sublime text2 , i compile from terminal. I use NASM. but i dont know if the corret syntax. please help me.

```
MOV AX, CS              ; Load Segment Registers 
    MOV DS, AX 
    MOV ES, AX
```

Begin:

```
; Welcome 

    MOV AH, 4                               ; CLS 
    INT 21h 

MOV SI, MSG_Welcome 
MOV AH, 1 
INT 21h 

XOR AH, AH 
INT 16h 

CMP AL, '0' 
JE SHORT End_Program 

CMP AL, '1' 
JE SHORT StartGame1 

CMP AL, '2' 
JE SHORT StartGame2 

CMP AL, '3' 
JE SHORT StartGame3 

JMP SHORT Begin
```

End_Program:

```
    MOV AH, 4                               ; CLS 
    INT 21h 

MOV AH, 0 
INT 21h
```

StartGame1:

```
MOV AX, 1 
MOV [Speed], AX 
JMP SHORT StartGame
```

StartGame2:

```
MOV AX, 2 
MOV [Speed], AX 
JMP SHORT StartGame
```

StartGame3:

```
MOV AX, 3 
MOV [Speed], AX 
JMP SHORT StartGame
```

StartGame

```
MOV AH, 1 
MOV CX, 10280               ; Disable Coursor 
INT 10h 


; Init Player 1 Position 

MOV BYTE [PosPlayer1], 9 
MOV BYTE [LastPlayer1], 9 

; Init Player 2 Position 

MOV BYTE [PosPlayer2], 9 
MOV BYTE [LastPlayer2], 9 


; Init Ball Position 

MOV BYTE [XPos], 39 
MOV BYTE [LastX], 39 

MOV BYTE [YPos], 12 
MOV BYTE [LastY], 12 

; Init Direction of Ball 


MOV BYTE [DirectionX], 1 
MOV BYTE [DirectionY], 1 


    MOV AH, 4                               ; CLS 
    INT 21h 

; Print Game Screen 


CALL PrintPlayer1 
CALL PrintPlayer2 
CALL PrintBall 


DoGame: 

    PUSH CX 

.IfX: 


    MOV AL, [XPos] 
    CMP AL, 4 
    JB NEAR .CheckPlayer1 
    CMP AL, 75 
    JA NEAR .CheckPlayer2 

.IfY: 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    CMP AL, 2 
    JB NEAR .PosYDirection 
    CMP AL, 21 
    JA NEAR .NegYDirection 


.PrintTheBall: 


    ; Check If any Player pressed a key: 

    mov ah, 01h 
    int 16h 
    jz .DoPrint 

    xor ah, ah 
    int 16h 



    CMP AL, 'w' 
    JE .SubPlayer1 
    CMP AL, 's' 
    JE .AddPlayer1 

    CMP AL, 'o' 
    JE .SubPlayer2 
    CMP AL, 'l' 
    JE .AddPlayer2 

    JMP .DoPrint 


.AddPlayer1: 




    MOV AL, [PosPlayer1] 

    CMP AL, 17 
    JE SHORT .DoPrint 

    ADD AL, 1 
    MOV [PosPlayer1], AL  
    JMP SHORT .DoPrint 


.SubPlayer1: 

    MOV AL, [PosPlayer1] 

    CMP AL, 0 
    JE SHORT .DoPrint 

    SUB AL, 1 
    MOV [PosPlayer1], AL  
    JMP SHORT .DoPrint 

.AddPlayer2: 

    MOV AL, [PosPlayer2] 

    CMP AL, 17 
    JE SHORT .DoPrint 

    ADD AL, 1 
    MOV [PosPlayer2], AL 
    JMP SHORT .DoPrint  


.SubPlayer2: 

    MOV AL, [PosPlayer2] 

    CMP AL, 0 
    JE SHORT .DoPrint 

    SUB AL, 1 
    MOV [PosPlayer2], AL 
    JMP SHORT .DoPrint  


.DoPrint: 

    MOV AX, [XPos] 
    ADD AX, [DirectionX] 
    MOV [XPos], AX  

    MOV AX, [YPos] 
    ADD AX, [DirectionY] 
    MOV [YPos], AX  


    CALL PrintScreen            ; Print Game Screen 
    CALL PrintPlayer1 
    CALL PrintPlayer2 
    CALL PrintBall 


    CALL WaitTime 


    JMP ResumeGame 

 .PosXDirection: 

    MOV BYTE [DirectionX], 1 
    JMP NEAR .IfY 

 .NegXDirection: 

    MOV BYTE [DirectionX], -1 
    JMP NEAR .IfY 

 .PosYDirection: 

    MOV BYTE [DirectionY], 1 
    JMP NEAR .PrintTheBall 

 .NegYDirection: 

    MOV BYTE [DirectionY], -1 
    JMP NEAR .PrintTheBall 

.CheckPlayer1: 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer1] 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .PosXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer1] 
    ADD BL, 1 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .PosXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer1] 
    ADD BL, 2 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .PosXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer1] 
    ADD BL, 3 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .PosXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer1] 
    ADD BL, 4 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .PosXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer1] 
    ADD BL, 5 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .PosXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer1] 
    ADD BL, 5 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .PosXDirection 

    JMP .Player1Lost 

.CheckPlayer2: 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer2] 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .NegXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer2] 
    ADD BL, 1 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .NegXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer2] 
    ADD BL, 2 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .NegXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer2] 
    ADD BL, 3 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .NegXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer2] 
    ADD BL, 4 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .NegXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer2] 
    ADD BL, 5 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .NegXDirection 

    MOV AL, [YPos] 
    MOV BL, [PosPlayer2] 
    ADD BL, 6 

    CMP AL, BL 
    JE .NegXDirection 

    JMP .Player2Lost 

.Player2Lost: 

    MOV AH, 4                               ; CLS 
        INT 21h 

    MOV CX, 3085 
    MOV CX, 1543 
    MOV AH, 1 
    INT 10h 

    MOV SI, MSG_Player2_Lost 
    MOV AH, 1 
    INT 21h 

    MOV AH, 0 
    INT 21h 

.Player1Lost: 

        MOV AH, 4                               ; CLS 
        INT 21h 

    MOV CX, 3085 
    MOV CX, 1543 
    MOV AH, 1 
    INT 10h 

    MOV SI, MSG_Player1_Lost 
    MOV AH, 1 
    INT 21h 

    MOV AH, 0 
    INT 21h 



ResumeGame: 


    POP CX 

    JMP DoGame 





MOV AH, 4                               ; CLS 
    INT 21h 

MOV AH, 0 
INT 21h
```

WaitTime:

```
XOR AH, AH 
INT 1Ah 

MOV BX, DX 


.GetNewTime: 

    PUSH BX 
    XOR AH, AH 
    INT 1Ah 
    POP BX 

    SUB DX, BX 
    MOV AX, [Speed] 
    CMP DX, AX 
    JB SHORT .GetNewTime 

JMP ResumeGame
```

PrintScreen:

```
MOV DL, [XPos] 
MOV DH, [YPos] 
CALL LocateXY 
CALL PrintDummy 



MOV DL, [XPos] 
MOV DH, [YPos] 
SUB DL, 1 
SUB DH, 1 
CALL LocateXY 
CALL PrintDummy 

MOV DL, [XPos] 
MOV DH, [YPos] 
SUB DL, 1 
CALL LocateXY 
CALL PrintDummy 



MOV DL, [XPos] 
MOV DH, [YPos] 
SUB DH, 1 
CALL LocateXY 
CALL PrintDummy 



MOV DL, [XPos] 
MOV DH, [YPos] 
ADD DH, 1 
CALL LocateXY 
CALL PrintDummy 



MOV DL, [XPos] 
MOV DH, [YPos] 
ADD DL, 1 
CALL LocateXY 
CALL PrintDummy 




MOV DL, [XPos] 
MOV DH, [YPos] 
ADD DL, 1 
ADD DH, 1 
CALL LocateXY 
CALL PrintDummy 

MOV DL, [XPos] 
MOV DH, [YPos] 
ADD DL, 1 
SUB DH, 1 
CALL LocateXY 
CALL PrintDummy 

MOV DL, [XPos] 
MOV DH, [YPos] 
SUB DL, 1 
ADD DH, 1 
CALL LocateXY 
CALL PrintDummy 





RETN
```

PrintPlayer1:

```
; Clear Last Position of Player 

MOV DH, [LastPlayer1] 
MOV DL, 3 

CALL LocateXY 

MOV CX, 6 

.ClearOldPos: 

    CALL PrintSpace 
    CALL PrintSpace 

    INC DH 
    MOV DL, 3 

    CALL LocateXY 
    LOOPNZ .ClearOldPos 

; Print Player 


MOV DH, [PosPlayer1] 
MOV DL, 3 

CALL LocateXY 

MOV CX, 6 
.PrintPos: 

    CALL PrintBlock 
    CALL PrintBlock 

    INC DH 
    MOV DL, 3 

    CALL LocateXY 
    LOOPNZ .PrintPos 

MOV AL, [PosPlayer1] 
MOV [LastPlayer1], AL 

RETN
```

PrintPlayer2:

```
; Clear Last Position of Player 

MOV DH, [LastPlayer2] 
MOV DL, 76 

CALL LocateXY 

MOV CX, 6 

.ClearOldPos: 

    CALL PrintSpace 
    CALL PrintSpace 

    INC DH 
    MOV DL, 76 

    CALL LocateXY 
    LOOPNZ .ClearOldPos 

; Print Player 


MOV DH, [PosPlayer2] 
MOV DL, 76 

CALL LocateXY 

MOV CX, 6 

.PrintPos: 

    CALL PrintBlock 
    CALL PrintBlock 

    INC DH 
    MOV DL, 76 

    CALL LocateXY 
    LOOPNZ .PrintPos 


MOV AL, [PosPlayer2] 
MOV [LastPlayer2], AL 

RETN
```

PrintBall:

```
; Clear Last Position of Ball 

MOV AL, [XPos] 
MOV [LastX], AL 

MOV AL, [YPos] 
MOV [LastY], AL 

; Print New Ball 

MOV DL, [XPos] 
MOV DH, [YPos] 

CALL LocateXY 
CALL PrintB      

RETN
```

PrintSpace:

```
MOV AH, 11 
MOV AL, ' ' 
INT 21h 
RETN
```

PrintDummy:

```
MOV AH, 11 
MOV AL, ' ' 
INT 21h 
RETN
```

PrintBlock:

```
MOV AH, 11 
MOV AL, '²' 
INT 21h 
RETN
```

PrintB:

```
MOV AH, 11 
MOV AL, 'Û' 
INT 21h 
RETN
```

LocateXY:

```
; DL = X 
; DH = Y 

PUSH AX 
PUSH BX 

MOV AH, 02h 
MOV BH, 0 
INT 10h 

POP BX 
POP AX 


RETN 


    PosPlayer1   DB 0 
LastPlayer1  DB 0 
    PosPlayer2   DB 0 
LastPlayer2  DB 0 


    XPos         DB 0 
LastX        DB 0 
    YPos         DB 0 
LastY        DB 0 

DirectionX    DB 0  ; -1 and +1 
DirectionY    DB 0  ; -1 and +1 

Speed   DB 0 


MSG_Player1_Lost    DB 'Player 1 lost the game!',13,10,0 
MSG_Player2_Lost    DB 'Player 2 lost the game!',13,10,0 

MSG_Welcome     
            DB 'This game is made for two player. The aim of the game is to bounce the ball',13,10, 
            DB 'so that it can not reach the screen boarder.',13,10, 
            DB 'Player 1 controlls his block with the Key >W< to move it upwards and >S< to',13,10, 
            DB 'move it downwards. Player 2 controlls his key with >O< for upwards and >L<',13,10, 
            DB 'downwards.',13,10, 
            DB 'The game will be terminated when a Player lost.',13,10,13,10, 
            DB 'Choose your game speed. After pressing the option the game will be started.',13,10, 
            DB ' 0 - terminate the game',13,10, 
            DB ' 1 - fast',13,10, 
            DB ' 2 - middle',13,10, 
            DB ' 3 - slow',13,10, 
            DB 'Your Option: ',0 



Dummy   TIMES 10 DB 0
```

Comment: `INT 21h`.. `INT 16h` - this is clearly non-Linux ABI, so you should rewrite whole program, OR use DOS (like FreeDOS or MS-DOS) to assemble and run it. This program will not run under ubuntu. You can try to find DOS emulator like DOSBox, or PC emulator like qemu or bochs and install DOS into them.

Comment: I'll do what you say.

Comment: just gives me an error. violation of the segment ('core' generated)

Comment: What you did? Rewrite the program for linux?

Answer (score 0):

The "Floppy Disk Operating System" project - http://sourceforge.net/projects/fdosx86/ 
was active in 2002-2004.

You should try to use nasm from the 2004. You can try to run nasm version from the fdos.tar.gz - download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/fdosx86/files/FDOS%200.0.9/FDOS%200.0.9%20SP%204%20DE_EN_SP/

Also it is hard to answer what is wrong with your syntax without exact messages from your nasm, and exact version of your nasm.

You should remember, that the program designed to be run in DOS (at least in FDOS, don't know about other DOSes)